# Get the count of records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that looks like this:

[image]

which is defined using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    p.p_ccode AS C_CODE,
    p.p_pcode AS P_CODE,
    p.p_phcode AS PH_CODE,
    PO.m_doc_type AS TYPE,
    PO.crtime AS DATE
FROM 
    TABLE1 AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DOCTABLE AS PO ON PO.m_ccode = p.p_ccode
                   AND PO.m_pcode = p.p_pcode
                   AND PO.m_phcode = p.p_phcode
```

Now I want to count the records for another table (`TABLE 2`) based on the `C_CODE`, `P_CODE` and `PH_CODE` and display it as a column `TOTAL` in my view.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.p_ccode AS C_CODE,
    p.p_pcode AS P_CODE,
    p.p_phcode AS PH_CODE,
    PO.m_doc_type AS TYPE,
    PO.crtime AS DATE,
    (select count(*) from tale2 t2 where t2.C_CODE = p.p_ccode and t2.P_CODE = p.P_CODE and t2.PH_CODE = p.PH_CODE) as total
FROM TABLE1 AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTABLE AS PO 
    ON PO.m_ccode = p.p_ccode
    AND PO.m_pcode = p.p_pcode
    AND PO.m_phcode = p.p_phcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join to it, group by and then count --

```sql
SELECT
    p.p_ccode AS C_CODE,
    p.p_pcode AS P_CODE,
    p.p_phcode AS PH_CODE,
    PO.m_doc_type AS TYPE,
    PO.crtime AS DATE,
    COUNT(P2.*) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLE1 AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTABLE AS PO 
    ON PO.m_ccode = p.p_ccode
    AND PO.m_pcode = p.p_pcode
    AND PO.m_phcode = p.p_phcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 AS p2
    ON p.m_ccode = p2.p_ccode
    AND p.m_pcode = p2.p_pcode
    AND p.m_phcode = p2.p_phcode
GROUP BY p.p_ccode, p.p_pcode, p.p_phcode, PO.m_doc_type, PO.crtime
```

Answer (score 0):

use an CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH CTE_COUNT
AS(
    SELECT 
         [C_CODE]
        ,[P_CODE]
        ,[PH_CODE]      
        ,COUNT(*) AS [TOTAL]
    FROM [dbo].[TABLE2]
    GROUP BY
         [C_CODE]
        ,[P_CODE]
        ,[PH_CODE]
)

SELECT 
     t1.[C_CODE]
    ,t1.[P_CODE]
    ,t1.[PH_CODE]
    ,t1.[TYPE]
    ,t1.[DATE]
    ,t2.[TOTAL]
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1] AS t1

LEFT JOIN CTE_COUNT AS t2
    ON  t2.[C_CODE] = t1.[C_CODE]
    AND t2.[P_CODE] = t1.[P_CODE]
    AND t2.[PH_CODE] = t1.[PH_CODE]
```